# How to deal with template re-parsing when changing the liquid version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, liquid

We store in our database **parsed** template and don't want to store the source liquid code as it takes a lot of space in our database.

This works great however, we are not sure how to deal with upgrade of the liquid gem. We noticed that an upgrade often requires to parse the liquid code again so the template is up to date. But this doesn't seems to be documented anywhere ‍♂️.

How should we deal with liquid upgrades ?

- Should we have a migration task that get back the initial liquid source code and recompile it ?
- Is there a way to "re-parse" a template with a new version of the liquid gem ?
- Is there a way to "un-parse" a template so we get access to the original source code again ?

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I'm curious. How do you store the parsed template in the database? Is parsing it from the stored way faster than just parsing the template? How much space does it take compared to the source template?

Comment: Store it as raw data (using Marshal.dump and Marshal.load). I never tested it myself but it's more efficient, no syntax validation no parsing, just loading. It takes a bit more space than the raw template.

Answer (score -1):

You can subscribe to theme update webhooks. Whenever you get one, download your liquid templates, re-parse them, save them and move on.

Comment: It's not about theme update but liquid version upgrade. Let's say you have a "compiled" liquid template that was compiled by liquid v3, how do you ensure it will work with liquid v6 without having to "recompile" it

Comment: When you update your gem, re-compile your templates. What does this have to do with Shopify anyway?

Comment: I guess shopify the company did these kinds of optimizations already and I'm curious. And space is indeed not a problem, but dealing with database entries 40% lighter makes everything faster: between the database and the app, and, between raw data to in memory ruby object.